# how to initialize tinymce with default content in laravel

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I want put the below code on a tinymce textarea but only part of code put on the textarea

```
<pre class="brush: php">
    &lt;?php
        some php code;      
</pre>
<!-- pagebreak -->
```

my codes for do this action is

```
<textarea name="text" id="tinyarea">{!! $tutorial->text !!}</textarea>
```

"$tutorial->text" is my code 

only below code put on the textarea

```
<pre class="brush: php">&nbsp;</pre>
```

It seams the problem is non php end tag (?>), if i remove `&lt;?php` the problem is solved, is there a way for this problem without deleting `&lt;?php`

English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: Why don't you try to add an end tag `?>` after `some php code`?

Comment: Ok thanks,was out of curiosity